# Multiple Where Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I am using linq c# to get the services ids selected by user `OrderId`

Since the user can have multiple `OrderId` I need to get the services of each id.

For this I am using `foreach` loop and getting the `ServiceId` from the database. This is taking long time to check for every `OrderId`, and `ServiceId` can be in list form.

Is there any method to get the result by calling database one time only?

Further the `OrderId` must be distinguishable for example how many services on each id.

**Code**

```
foreach (var ord in orderInfoDetailList)
{
    // this taking very long time if there are too many orderids    
    long orderid = ord.orderObj.OrderID;
    var services = (from i in db.OrderServiceTBs 
                    where i.OrderID == orderid
                    select i.ServiceID).ToList();
}
```

Comment: What you are doing with `services`? The question is unclear, i don't know how to improve without knowing what you are trying to do.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: have you tried using `orderInfoDetailList.Contains(iOrderID)`?

Comment: @Console this does not scale well and crashes for longer lists.

Comment: How do you get orderInfoDetailList? If you get it in one query, you can get services in one simple query too. If it is just arbitrary list and you are on mssql server, have a look at TVP (table valued parameters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all service-id's you should use this join approach (no `foreach`):

```
var allServiceIDs = from o in orderInfoDetailList
                    join i in db.OrderServiceTBs 
                    on o.orderObj.OrderID equals i.OrderID 
                    select i.ServiceID;
var list = allServiceIDs.ToList(); // if you get duplicates use Distinct() before ToList()
```

> But how will I distinguish which service on which orderid because
>   this gives list?

Well, you haven't mentioned this anywehere in your question. However, you could use following query to create a dictionary, where the `OrderId` is the `Key` and the `Value` are all `ServiceID`:

```
var orderGroups = from o in orderInfoDetailList
                  join i in db.OrderServiceTBs 
                  on o.orderObj.OrderID equals i.OrderID 
                  group i by o.OrderID into orderGroup
                  select orderGroup;
var orderLookup = orderGroups.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.ServiceID).ToList());
```

Comment: According to my tests this queries the whole OrderServiceTBs table and filters it on client, which is terribly inefficient.

Comment: But how will I distinguish which service on which orderid because this gives list?

Comment: @JustForTest: you haven't mentioned that this is important

Comment: Sorry please tell me how to do this.

Comment: change the `select` to `select new { i.ServiceID, i.OrderID }` this will create a anonymous object with both values

Comment: @JustForTest: one approach is using `group by`, f.e. to create a dictionary. I've shown this approach above. Then you can even access every list via the `OrderId`.

Answer (score 1):

It's like you are trying to find all instances of dropdown id's which present in any of the orderInfoDetailList values. If so try the following

```
var services =  db.OrderServiceTBs.Where(i=>orderInfoDetailList.Any(x=>x.orderObj.OrderID == i.OrderID)).Select(x=> x.ServiceID).ToList();
```

Comment: But how will I distinguish which service on which orderid because this gives list?